# Google App Engine Managed VMs for Go: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CleanableContainerName'

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-platform

On a Mac OS X, trying to turn on the debug flag or to run the hello world test project for Go Managed VMs, I am getting the following error: **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CleanableContainerName'**

Any ideas?

Full error log:

```
orcaman$ $(boot2docker shellinit)
Writing /Users/orcaman/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem
Writing /Users/orcaman/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/cert.pem
Writing /Users/orcaman/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/key.pem

orcaman$ gcloud --verbosity debug preview app setup-managed-vms
DEBUG: Running gcloud.preview.app.setup-managed-vms with _Args({'base_image_bucket': 'containers-prod',
 'docker_host': None,
 'format': None,
 'h': None,
 'help': None,
 'image_version': 'latest',
 'markdown': None,
 'project': None,
 'quiet': None,
 'shell': None,
 'user_output_enabled': None,
 'verbosity': 'debug'}).
DEBUG: Detected docker environment variables: DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376, DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/orcaman/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.59.103
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2
INFO: Looking for image_id for image with tag google/docker-registry
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/images/json?filter=google%2Fdocker-registry&only_ids=1&all=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 253
DEBUG: Found Cloud SDK root: /Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk
Select the runtime to download the base image for:
 [1] Go
 [2] Java
 [3] Python27
 [4] All
Please enter your numeric choice (4):  1

DEBUG: Detected docker environment variables: DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376, DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/orcaman/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.59.103
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2
Pulling base images for runtimes [go] from Google Cloud Storage
INFO: Refreshing access_token
DEBUG: Copy /Users/orcaman/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/orhiltch@gmail.com/.boto to /var/folders/dv/g8_pdljx49gdtbs25_1ch7vm0000gn/T/tmp7imPhg...
DEBUG: Copy /Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/docker/true-asm to /var/folders/dv/g8_pdljx49gdtbs25_1ch7vm0000gn/T/tmp7imPhg...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 177, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 173, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 409, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 928, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/setup_managed_vms.py", line 39, in Run
    args.image_version)
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/pull.py", line 54, in PullBaseDockerImages
    util.PullSpecifiedImages(docker_client, image_names, version, bucket)
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/util.py", line 217, in PullSpecifiedImages
    with credentials.CredentialsContainer(docker_client) as creds, (
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/credentials.py", line 114, in __enter__
    self.Start()
  File "/Users/orcaman/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/credentials.py", line 95, in Start
    name=containers.CleanableContainerName(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CleanableContainerName'
```

Docker/Boot2docker version:

```
bash-3.2$ docker version
Client version: 1.4.1
Client API version: 1.16
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 5bc2ff8
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.4.1
Server API version: 1.16
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 5bc2ff8
```

gcloud version:

```
gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.42

app 2015.01.06
app-engine-go-darwin-x86_64 1.9.17
app-engine-java 1.9.17
app-engine-managed-vms 2014.11.03
app-engine-python 1.9.17
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2015.01.06
core 2015.01.06
core-nix 2014.10.20
dns 2015.01.06
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-nix 1.16.5
gsutil 4.7
gsutil-nix 4.6
preview 2015.01.06
preview-extensions-darwin-x86_64 0.7.0
sql 2015.01.06
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
The fix for gcloud is now available in the latest version and this issue should be resolved.

**Previous Post:**

As a temporary workaround you can run:

```
gcloud components restore
```

There may be a bug in the latest gcloud update.  I saw the same error after updating - but is working now after running the above command.